# Ubuntu 20.10 freshly Install doesn't boot normally [Recovery Mode]

Tags: boot, initramfs, 20.10, amd-ryzen, amdgpu-pro

I recently installed the new Ubuntu 20.10, after the first reboot when I choose **Ubuntu** from grub's black screen I got this error

```
[     0.298008] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
/dev/sdb5: Clean, 207672/6225920 files, 3573307/24882688 blocks
```

I search the internet for a solution and I got and apply this one:

```
I changed COMPRESS=lz4 to COMPRESS=gzip in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
then sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
```

Then I tried to boot to the normal Ubuntu, I got this error

```
/dev/sdb3: Clean, 203431/6234112 files, 2806098/24907008 blocks
```

and during these error messages, my PC fully stuck and I cannot hit `CTRL/ALT + F1 or F2`

And when I want to open Ubuntu I enter the [Recovery Mode] with messy resolution and bad graphics!

```
My PC specs
MB: MSI B450 Tomahawk Max
CPU: AMD® Ryzen 5 1600AF
GPU: AMD® Rx 570 4G <<< I think Ubuntu cannot install the driver, and the official driver is showing me an error also!
MEM: 16G
SSD: sda [Windows] 120G
HDD: sdb [Ubuntu] + Data on ntfs drive
```

Kindly help me to sort this problem out, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this may suck as a comment or suggestion to some, but can you try 20.04 LTS if you are able to? It may help limit the issue down to 20.10 as it is a far newer and *less stable* release, and LTS has the most framework. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank You, but I faced the same problem with 20.04 LTS too! that's why I decided to use 20.10 although the error existed!
I think all this mess and problems because the graphics card Rx 570 doesn't install correctly!

Comment: Oh jeez, that definitely shoots my idea to pieces then! I have absolutely no idea what is causing this issue, it seems rather strange but I would imagine someone on here with a lot more experience than me has some idea or at least has seen this problem before. Very sorry I couldn't help!

Comment: No worries, you already did, you helped me, thank you.